# Number of employees of large companies?

Tags: data-request, companies

Where can I find the numbers of employees of large companies?

Are there any open source or free information sources available?

Comment: Data.gov claims that "it is possible to estimate the number of employees a given company has based on existing, publicly available data about participants its retirement plan" and sends to https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/ebsa-form-5500-annual-return-report-filing-enforcement-data#topic=finance_navigation .

Answer (score 3):

http://finance.yahoo.com

GE for example `Full Time Employees:    305,000`:

http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=GE+Profile

And https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Query_Language for auto extraction.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this question is older but i was searching for the same thing.

There is also a dataset from 2018 on Kaggle:

https://www.kaggle.com/Eruditepanda/fortune-1000-2018