# Public companies' employee count and properties from SEC/Edgar 10-K

Tags: data-request, companies, real-estate

I've browsed through several 10-K documents and found that companies provide their employee headcount (under Item 1. Business) and properties they own or lease (Item 2. Properties). ([Yahoo example](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1011006/000119312513085111/d442073d10k.htm).)

I saw [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5010/number-of-employees-of-large-companies) for employee numbers, but the answer does not provide a timeseries or property info.

Has anybody extracted these data elements from the 10-K text (per year) and made them openly available? Thanks!